# trying to learn QML for Qt... issue with example

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Example... not sure what I am doing wrong...
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtbinding.html

[image]

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QDeclarativeEngine engine;
    QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
    QObject *object = component.create();

    QVariant returnedValue;
    QVariant msg = "Hello from C++";
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "myQmlFunction",
            Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
            Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));

    qDebug() << "QML function returned:" << returnedValue.toString();
    delete object;

}
```

---

```
// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    function myQmlFunction(msg) {
        console.log("Got message:", msg)
        return "some return value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `QT += declarative` in your `.pro` file ?

Comment: yes... 
QT       += core gui\
        declarative

Comment: Something to consider is if you are using QtCreator you tell it to create a QtQuick application and it will auto generate all the C++ and setup your pro file for you.  This allows you to jump straight into the QML or to review the code it generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QT += declarative. Note you do not need to add "core" and "gui" even though QtCreator may autogenerate those a bit uselessly. Note, you also had the mainwindow.h included from the main.cpp without any use of it, so I removed that below, too. This builds fine for me:

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
QT += declarative
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QDeclarativeEngine engine;
    QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
    QObject *object = component.create();

    QVariant returnedValue;
    QVariant msg = "Hello from C++";
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "myQmlFunction",
        Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
        Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));

    qDebug() << "QML function returned:" << returnedValue.toString();
    delete object;

}
```

Then just run `qmake && (n)make/jom` for a test.